# Индекс статей при переезде

Tags: wordpress

Ситуация такая:
есть сайт на WordPress на бесплатной платформе. Постоянный поток посетителей, статьи в индексе и т.д. и т.п.

Как бы там ни было, а сайт я хочу удалить и перенести (а может и нет; я ещё не решил) на новое место. И тут вопрос: что случится с индексом? Мои статьи переиндексируются, а старые пропадут?

Ещё проблема, что на старом хостинге переадресацию поставить нереально - такая там администрация.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно делать 301 редирект.

Если меняется только домен, то достаточно просто сделать редирект всех запросов на новых домен. Если меняется и структура сайта (урлы), то нужно каждый текст редиректить со старого урла на новый.

Яндекс отлично понимает редирект с кодом 301, ничего не вывалится из индекса.

На всякий случай - [генератор htacccess](http://htaccess.ru/generator/)

Насчет невозможности ставить редирект, кто вам мешает сделать это прямо в коде? Если это какой нибудь юкоз, ну поставьте мета тегом, это помоему можно.

Если редирект не сделать, то поисковики ничего не обещают на этот счет. Может быть переиндексируется, может быть нет. ХЗ

Comment: а если без редиректа?
что будет, если удалить статью по старому адресу и опубликовать её же по новому? Она проиндексируется?

Comment: @autumnrustle по-моему, сейчас поисковые системы не любят скопипащеный контент, а именно за такой он примется на новом домене без редиректов.

Comment: У нас однажды был такой факапчик, сайт переехал на другую цмску, а редиректы не поставили. На месяц сайт из индекса вывалился, потом внезапно вернулся.

Вроде сейчас в Яндекс Вебмастере есть что то для такого переезда, по крайней мере можно скормить новую карту сайта, для ускорения переиндексации